# Converting Webm audio file to flac on Java Spring for Google Cloud Speech-To-Text API

Tags: java, google-speech-api

I have webm audio file and would like to convert to flac/Linear16 which is supported by Google cloud speech API. Any idea how I can do that?

On React frontend, I am using ReactMic to get the recorded audio.

```
<ReactMic
    className="w-10 h-1 aspect-ratio ml2"
    record={this.props.recording}
    onData={this.props.onData}
    onStop={this.props.onStop}
    strokeColor="#FFFFFF"
 />
 </div>
    <div className="ma3">
         <Button onClick={this.props.onStartRecord}>Start Recording</Button>
         <Button onClick={this.props.onStopRecord}>Stop Recording</Button>
    </div>
```

// The respective functions

```
onStartRecord = e => {
    this.setState({ recording: true });
};

onStopRecord = e => {
    this.setState({ recording: false });
};

onStop = recordedBlob => {
    this.setState({ recordedAudio: recordedBlob });
};
```

The recorded audio is then being send as HTTP Post request

```
let fd = new FormData();
fd.append("audio", this.state.recordedAudio.blob);

fetch(this.props.url + "speeches/", {
  method: "post",
  body: fd
})
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(data => {
    this.setState({ result: data });
  });
```

On Java Spring backend, I will receive the the audio as MultipartFile

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/speeches", method = RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> speechToText(@RequestBody MultipartFile audio) {

   return itemService.speechToText(audio);
}
```

The problem now is that the file is in webm format, which is not supported by Google Cloud Speech-To-Text API. Is there a way to convert to flac/linear16 format either at frontend or backend. Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Please add the code you already tried so we can have a look at it.

Comment: Hi @FabianSchöner I have added my code. Pardon for the lack of information!

Comment: Exact same boat, I've extracted the blobs from the MediaRecorder, but the only supported formats are 'audio/webm'.  But their API doesn't have that as a supported format, and it seems there aren't any libraries for converting webm to any of their supported formats.  Which is ridiculous because google authored the webm format